# Aliasing path expansion

Tags: symlink, alias, dropbox

I've recently switched from my personal Dropbox to a company one.

This means that my Dropbox folder is now named "Dropbox (Company)" from "Dropbox".

Now I had all my work under my personal DB folder, and a few aliases to quickly access folders e.g. `alias cdre="cd /home/user/Dropbox/Work/repos/`

Is there a way for all my aliases to continue working with the new directory without changing them?

I've tried soft-linking `/home/user/Dropbox` to `/home/user/Dropbox\ \(Company\)` but  that doesn't seem to work for aliases. I've also tried aliasing `Dropbox=Dropbox\ \(Company\)` but that doesn't seem to get "nested" expansion when used for example the above `cdre` alias.

Any ideas? What would be the least painful way to deal with this, also because of the brilliant idea of DB to include spaces and parentheses in the directory name, which we cannot change.

Comment: Soft-linking should work. Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work?

Comment: Please add the output of the following command to your question: `ls -d /home/user/Drop*` as I believe help requires a more complete picture of where the directories are and how they are named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a symbolic link like this:

```
ln -s "$HOME/Dropbox (Company)" "$HOME/Dropbox"
```

... then you should be all set and aliases should not need to be changed (since accessing `$HOME/Dropbox` would take you to `$HOME/Dropbox (Company)` through the symbolic link).

This assumes that you have moved the original `$HOME/Dropbox` directory out of the way, or you would have had issues with creating the link correctly.

Comment: You were correct, I was messing up the order in the arguments there, thanks!